# Problema tela de login, caso usuario logado redirecionar para telaInicio

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, filter

Boa tarde, estou com um sistema, consegui fazer o filtro em caso do usuário não esteja logado na sessão, redirecionar para tela de login. 
Só que agora estou tentando fazer ao contrário, caso o usuário esteja logado e ele tentar acessar a tela de login, redirecionar para a tela de inicio.

Segue abaixo meu código

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Awake</display-name>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>loginAdm.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

 <error-page>
   <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception- type>
   <location>/loginAdm.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>

 <!--  login filter -->
<filter>
  <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>br.com.awake.LoginFilter</filter-class>    
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

 <session-config>
   <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
```

LoginFilter.java

```
package br.com.awake;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import br.com.awake.model.AdministradorModel;

public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

     public void destroy() {

     }

     public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

         AdministradorModel user = null;
         HttpSession sess = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession(false);

         if (sess != null){
               user =  (AdministradorModel) sess.getAttribute("usuarioLogado");
         }      

               if (user == null) {
                        String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request)
                                           .getContextPath();
                        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(contextPath
                                           + "/loginAdm.xhtml");
               } else {
                        chain.doFilter(request, response);
               }

     }

     public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

     }
```

SessionContext.java

```
package br.com.awake;

import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import br.com.awake.model.AdministradorModel;

public class SessionContext {

private static SessionContext instance;

public static SessionContext getInstance(){
     if (instance == null){
         instance = new SessionContext();
     }

     return instance;
}

private SessionContext(){

}

private ExternalContext currentExternalContext(){
     if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() == null){
         throw new RuntimeException("O FacesContext não pode ser chamado fora de uma requisição HTTP");
     }else{
         return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
     }
}

public AdministradorModel getUsuarioLogado(){
     return (AdministradorModel) getAttribute("usuarioLogado");
}

public void setUsuarioLogado(AdministradorModel usuario){
     setAttribute("usuarioLogado", usuario);
}

public void encerrarSessao(){   
     currentExternalContext().invalidateSession();
}

public Object getAttribute(String nome){
     return currentExternalContext().getSessionMap().get(nome);
}

public void setAttribute(String nome, Object valor){
     currentExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(nome, valor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

eu costumo fazer assim (não sei se é a melhor forma):

No trecho

```
if (user == null) {
                    String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request)
                                       .getContextPath();
                    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(contextPath
                                       + "/loginAdm.xhtml");
           } else {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
           }
```

No else, você pode verificar o contextPath. Se for igual à página de login, ao invés de fazer

```
chain.doFilter(request,response);
```

faça

```
res.sendRedirect(paginaDeLogin);
```

e se não for igual, aí você faz o chain.doFilter...

Espero tê-lo ajudado.